# fileName.java:1 error ';' expected - Visual Studio Cordova Build with Android plugin

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, plugins, plugman

I have used the plugman command from the [tutorial](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/createplugintutorial/)

.  It has created the necessary files for a test plugin which I have not amended.  I have added the plugin to my cordova visual studio project using the Plugins tab of config.xml to this local plugin.  When I build I get the error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       C:\Users\tonyh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AmILateTestDelete\AmILateTestDelete\platforms\android\src\cordova-plugin-am-i-late\AmILate\AmILate.java:1: error: ';' expected    AmILateTestDelete       1

```
package cordova-plugin-am-i-late;
```

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * This class echoes a string called from JavaScript.
 */

public class AmILate extends CordovaPlugin {

```
@Override

public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        if (action.equals("coolMethod")) {

        String message = args.getString(0);

        this.coolMethod(message, callbackContext);

        return true;

    }

        return false;

    }


private void coolMethod(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {

        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {

                callbackContext.success(message);

    } else {

                callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");

    }

    }
```

}

Has anyone encountered this problem ?

Many thanks.

Tony

Comment: Hi, Did you get the answer for this problem. I am still facing the same problem. And no clue what to do to fix it.

Comment: Have you looked at the advice from Jordan ?  It has been so long since this post that I cannot remember if I did resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

Your package name contains hyphens (-), which aren't valid characters in an identifier name (they can be confused with a subtraction/`-` operation). Try removing those and your file should compile.